# Active memory of Mobile - android

Tags: android, memory, ram

Hi all hope you all are doing great,
guys i have a issue that how can we get the Active, Inactive and Wired memory usage of a android device if we use **adb shell cat /proc/meminfo** for getting Ram size i get a big string which has active and inactivy memory
here is the code for the same

```
    ProcessBuilder cmd;

    StringBuffer strMemory = new StringBuffer();
    // final ActivityManager activityManager =(ActivityManager)
    // context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    actvityManager.getMemoryInfo(mInfo);

    strMemory.append("Available Memory : ");
    strMemory.append(mInfo.availMem / 1048576L);
    strMemory.append("\n");
    strMemory.append("\n");

    String result = strMemory.toString();

    try {
        String[] args = { "/system/bin/cat", "/proc/meminfo" };
        cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

        Process process = cmd.start();
        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        byte[] re = new byte[1024];
        while (in.read(re) != -1) {
            // System.out.println("itthhe   ====  ---   >>>>    "+new
            // String(re));
            String str = new String(re);
            // int a = Integer.parseInt(str);
            System.out.println("oiiidd str 11111111111 --->>>   " +     str);
            // Long aa = Long.parseLong(str)/1048576L;
            String st = "Active";
            System.out.println("oii0--->>>>   "+st.substring(0,2));
            int l1 = st.length();

            if (l1 > 3) { l1 = 4; }

            System.out.println("oiiidd str  --->>>   " + str);
            if (str.startsWith(st.substring(0,l1))) 
            {
                System.out.println(str+"      -------------------printed dude ");
             // do something..
            }

            result = result + new String(re);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

now from here i am getting big string

```
MemTotal:         256556 kB
MemFree:           93576 kB
Buffers:            1036 kB
Cached:            70064 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            97496 kB
Inactive:          48828 kB
Active(anon):      79884 kB
Inactive(anon):        0 kB
Active(file):      17612 kB
Inactive(file):    48828 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         75244 kB
Mapped:            36340 kB
Slab:               4528 kB
SReclaimable:       1448 kB
SUnreclaim:         3080 kB
PageTables:         6864 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      128276 kB
Committed_AS:    1084956 kB
VmallocTotal:     712704 kB
VmallocUsed:       22596 kB
VmallocChunk:     684036 kB
```

now how can i parse active and inactive data ,

and is there any other way to find or this is the only way to finding these data`

Comment: First of all, you don't need (and should not use) cat, you should just read the file directly.  Second, java has the usual assortment of methods in the String class, look it up and you should find some ideas (there are also fancier parsing systems, but you hardly need that)

Comment: Thanks Chris Stratton, i tried and it worked, but i am  not able to find wired memory , do you have any idea how can we get wired memory
i have no clue how will i find this, any help is appriciated 
thanks in advance
and thank you very much for your precious reply

Comment: What is "wired" memory?  Practically speaking, any memory physically present but not available to the kernel should not be of interest to a 3rd party app developer - it's probably reserved for a radio firmware or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the DDMS in the SDK

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/track-mem.html

Comment: DDMS is a host tool, the poster appears to be trying to do something within an application running on the device.